# Corrupted TFS project

Tags: tfs

I'm banging my head for several hours but couldn't find the solution on my problem. I have a team project collection. one of the project in collection is corrupted probably. It doesn't show up either in Team Explorer nor in TFS Administrator. but I can see that project in Source Control Explorer from VS. I tried TFSDeleteProject but it says:

```
TF200016: The following project does not exist:........
```

I can't create a team project with same name, nor I can delete it.
I looked at the database and there are entries about the corrupt project in many tables. Any idea how to remove it? maybe with the help of some SPs? I tried DeleteProject stored procedure, it didn't show an error, but it also didn't delete the project.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply deleting it from source control?

TFS is comprised of several components (issue tracker, reports, source control, etc.), which, although typically used together, can also function individually. A file/folder in source control that does not belong to any project is thus possible. I don't know if you can create this situation manually, but it could result from a bug.

Comment: Delete button is disabled from SC Explorer :(

Comment: @Davita - are you an admin on the TFS server? Maybe it cannot calculate permissions, but a System Administrator might still be able to get them.

Comment: Nope, I'm admin. I have full control over TFS :(

Comment: @Davita - Then it seems you really are in trouble. My guess is that the DB really is corrupted. Sadly I'm not aware of any repair tools. :( Perhaps googling might help, I haven't used TFS in a while. But I did try to reverse-engineer it some time ago. It wasn't that bad. Maybe you can try to edit the DB directly and delete the project from there (all data, including source control, is in MSSQL DB). Though make a good backup beforehand, it's not very...normalized, thus it can be easily corrupted even further.

Comment: Yep, I'm in trouble :). I'll wait if anyone posts a better solution. If not I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks for your support Vilx and vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tfsdeleteproject to remove this.

The DB isn't corrupt, you cannot delete Team Project level source control folders through the UI.

```
tfsdeleteproject /collection:<url> <teamproject|srcfoldername>
```

You can always get the collection url by selecting the collection node in Team Explorer and hitting F4 to view the properties pane.  Copy/paste the url.  The Source Control folder you are trying to delete is *likely* the same as your Team project name.